# Discrepancy between Kepler GL coordinates and Google Maps

Tags: deck.gl, kepler.gl

I'm trying to create a map layer with a point in https://kepler.gl/demo, but I'm facing that the coordinates that I'm using are rendering differently in Google Maps and in Kepler GL.

This is the geojson that I am loading in kepler gl:

{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [42.2812989, -8.7366615]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "foo"
    }
  }

This puts a point in the middle of the sea...but if I put those coordinates in Google Maps the point is in Galicia (Spain), which is the 'real' location.

Maybe there is something that I'm not taking in count?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the coordinates. First the longitude and then the latitude. Then you will see your point in its real location.